# How to change view of my viewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I can change the class of the view in an UIViewController using the Storyboard like so:
[image]

How can I achieve the same effect programmatically?
I've tried this:

```
convenience init() {
    print("convenience init")
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.view = MTKView()
}
```

But it doesn't work. Seems to change the view for the MTKView, but the frame doesn't resize like it does when doing this by the Storyboard.

Answer (score 9):

You should implement the [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview?language=objc) function in your view controller and assign an instance of your custom view to the view controller's `view` property:

```
override func loadView() {
    self.view = MyCustomView(frame: ...)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The app crashes. So it doesn't have the same effect as visually setting the class in Storyboard. I'm looking for that same result.

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: Was a Metal related crash, by setting the frame it worked: self.view = MTKView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds). Thanks.